# How to identify from where it got trigger

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jaws-screen-reader

I have two trigger point one is **edit icon** and other is **add save button** . on click on edit iocn and save button one model get open . model is same for both .

I want to make back focus on click on (x) icon of model from where it got trigger .
how should i identify from where it got trigger from **edit iocn** or from **add save button** . and how to back focus on them ?

Comment: What is "it"? How are you calling "it"? Where is your code?

Comment: How does the tag `jaws-screen-reader` come into play for this question?  Are the icons not being read correctly by the screen reader?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this by passing a value into your function. Let me make it clear by following example.

So there are two buttons

```
<button onclick="myFunction('edit')">Edit</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('save')">Save</button>
```

and Javascript function will look something like this

```
<script>
    function myFunction(event_type){
        if(event_type == 'edit'){
            //your further code for edit event goes here
        }
        else{
            //if event_type is not edit, then it's obviously save event
            //so your further code for save event goes here 
        }
    }
</script>
```